# how to check const char* values one by one

Tags: c++, char

I have a `const char*` variable which takes values from a function that I have wrote.

When I write this variable to a file many times it writes nothing. So it must be empty or filled in with space.The strange thing is that in the txt file that I write it changes line every time, when it has value or not.Why is that?Does it mean that the returned value from the function has a \n?

how can I check if a value of a `const char *` is empty or in general how can I check character by character the value in char*?

Comment: How are you using it? You're really better off with `std::string` anyway.

Comment: Not sure what the wrong is unless you show us the code. Any how, use **std::string** is my advice.

Comment: the function is from a library that return const char*, then I write the returned variable to my txt. and I see blank and newline.
How can I convert it to std::string? then std strcmp funtion will help me you think?

Comment: @ararar, You can convert it just by assigning the result to one because of the implicit conversion constructor: `std::string str = yourFunction();`. Then you can just use `if (str.empty())` or `if (str == "")` for emptiness, and do all sorts of other stuff more easily than with the `const char *`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C/C++ pointers can be interpreted as arrays of values the pointers point to, the two ways of checking values of a `char*` is by applying an indexing operator or by using pointer arithmetics. You can do this:

```
const char *p = myFunctionReturningConstChar();
for (int i = 0 ; p[i] ; i++) {
    if (p[i] == '\n') printf("New line\n");
}
```

or this:

```
const char *p = myFunctionReturningConstChar();
while (*p) {
    if (*p == '\n') printf("New line\n");
    p++;
}
```

In addition, C++ library [provides multiple functions for working with C strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/). You may find `strlen` helpful to check if your pointer points to an empty string.